# Unstyled navbar in different page

Tags: html, css

When linking another page for a second navbar shows it's inner code and I'm working with WordPress right now. I have deleted all background colors cause it's harder to understand the CSS code.

Site - http://qweqwe.co.nf/

Linking another page in process:

[image]

Here is how navbar is looks like

```
.site-header {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fefefe', endColorstr='#edeee8', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #999;
    border-bottom:solid 5px #686868;
    min-width: 960px;
}
.main-navigation {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fefefe', endColorstr='#edeee8', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    padding: 1.5rem 0 0 482px;
}
.nav-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
.nav-menu li {
    background:url(http://qwe.qwe/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/sting.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) {
    background:none;
}
.nav-menu li:nth-child(5) {
    background:none;
}
.nav-menu ul:nth-child(2) li {
    background:url(http://qwe.qwe/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/sting_.png);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nav-menu ul:nth-child(2) li:last-child {
    background:none
}
.nav-menu a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 6px 10px 21px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 21%);
    font-family:'HeliosCondC', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-menu .current_page_item > a, .nav-menu .current-menu-item > a, .nav-menu .current_page_item > a:hover .nav-menu .sub-menu li a, .nav-menu .current-menu-item > a:hover .nav-menu .sub-menu li a {
    background: #686868;
    color: white;
    border-radius: .5rem .5rem 0 0;
}
.nav-menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0 0 0 46rem;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.nav-menu .sub-menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-menu .sub-menu li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
.nav-menu .sub-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.nav-menu .sub-menu a {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: none;
    list-style: none;
    color:#777;
    padding: 2rem;
}
.nav-menu .sub-menu .current_page_item > a, .nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a, .nav-menu .sub-menu > a:hover, .nav-menu .sub-menu > a:hover {
    background: inherit;
    color: white;
}
.nav-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
.nav-menu .current_page_item ul, .nav-menu .current-menu-item ul, .nav-menu ul:hover, .nav-menu ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a demo.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you explain more?

Comment: http://qweqwe.co.nf/ here is the site, just try to push some of top navbar links and u ll understand what did i mean.

Comment: I think your website is down. Can you fix that and sent me the updated link?

Comment: Actually it's pretty much working, tryed to send u a link but couldnt find Private Message - here is a link - http://qweqwe.co.nf/ , and it's 100% works.

Comment: I tried but I can reach your website. http://qweqwe.co.nf/

Comment: It's kinda looks really disturbing, I dont know why is that happening, if u could help me with that  can give u my skype(vladnaiden) and give a remote control or something, just dont really know how to fix the problem and any help will be really appreciative